# Scikit-learn: ARI score for cluster evaluation

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis

I am calculating the Adjusted Rand index score for [evaluating the cluster performance](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#clustering-performance-evaluation). Suppose, the true cluster and predicted cluster looks like the following. The format `{i, "x"}` tells that the element `"x"` is in `ith` cluster.

```
>>> labels_true = [{0,"a"}, {0,"b"}, {0,"c"}, {1,"d"}, {1,"e"}, {1,"f"}]
>>> labels_pred = [{0,"a"}, {0,"b"}, {1,"c"}, {1,"d"}, {2,"e"}, {2,"f"}]
>>> metrics.adjusted_rand_score(labels_true, labels_pred)
```

The ARI score is coming 1.0, but it seems it should not be 1.0 as the predicted cluster is different from the true one.

I am wondering if it is a valid way to calculate ARI score.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just have to put the labels in the ARI score fonction :
`labels_true = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]`
`labels_pred = [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2]`
`metrics.adjusted_rand_score(labels_true, labels_pred)`